How to @mention a user in the Case feed when a related Known Issue is updated or created in Salesforce?
I have a Salesforce setup where:
Each Case record has a lookup to a Known Issue.
There is a custom field on the Case called Associate.
When a Known Issue record is created or updated, a Flow is triggered. Within the Flow, there is a check to see if the Associate field on the Case matches the Employee ID of a user in the User object.
How can I configure a autolaunched Flow to @mention the user in the Case's feed with a custom message whenever the Known Issue is created or updated, if a match is found?
I tried using the following formula and populating the feed item within the Flow, but the @mention is not properly tagging the user:


Does this answer your question? Flow - Create Chatter @ Mention Post

no, i tried and i still get a string

I have finally ended up using connect api
